# Making alias for system path

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I heard that there is a way to do alias for specific path 'programatically' so that I can specify the Link as how I want. Let say I have user edit page that has this link: 8082/user/edit
I want an alias that re-direct the user from 8082/user/edit to 8082/user/aboutus programatically.

Hope to here from you soon.

Answer (score 0):

With the pathauto module enabled, you can use [pathauto_create_alias](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!pathauto!pathauto.inc/function/pathauto_create_alias/7).
If you want to change the original url, you can use [HOOK_menu_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a system path, you can use hook_menu_alter to override the function associated with the edit page, and in a custom module add a new function that redirects programmatically to that users "aboutus" page.

If you have a one to one redirect, using the redirect module is fine.  But if you want to redirect each user's edit page to another dynamic page, you'd want to replace the original function in hook_menu_alter

So you'd change this:

```
  $items['user/%user/edit'] = array(
    'title' => 'Edit',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('user_profile_form', 1),
    'access callback' => 'user_edit_access',
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'file' => 'user.pages.inc',
  );
```

and replace the page callback to a custom function

```
  $items['user/%user/edit'] = array(
    'title' => 'Edit',
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_redirect_user_edit',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  );
```

then in your custom function, you can programatically redirect with drupal_goto

```
function mymodule_redirect_user_edit() {
  drupal_goto('user/' . arg(1) . '/aboutus'), array(), 301);
}
```